# Remove byte-order-mark in R/C

Tags: c, json, r, utf-8

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693842/how-do-i-post-a-json-formatted-request-to-get-json-data-from-a-url-in-r-into-the/26694408#26694408) has an example of a server that generates json with a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). RFC7159 says:

> Implementations MUST NOT add a byte order mark to the beginning of a JSON text. In the interests of interoperability, implementations that parse JSON texts MAY ignore the presence of a byte order mark rather than treating it as an error.

Currently [yajl](https://lloyd.github.io/yajl/) and hence [jsonlite](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html) choke on the BOM. I would like to follow the RFC suggestion and ignore the BOM from the UTF8 string if present. What is an efficient way to do this? A naive implementation:

```
if(substr(json, 1, 1) == "\uFEFF"){
  json <- substring(json, 2)
}
```

However `substr` is a bit slow for large strings, and I am not sure this is the correct way to do this. Is there a more efficient way in R or C to remove the BOM if present?

Comment: The UTF-8 representation of the BOM will be EF BB BF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::string stripBom(std::string x) {
   if (x.size() < 3)
      return x;

   if (x[0] == '\xEF' && x[1] == '\xBB' && x[2] == '\xBF')
      return x.substr(3);

   return x;
}

/*** R
x <- "\uFEFFabcdef"
print(x)
print(stripBom(x))
identical(x, stripBom(x))
utf8ToInt(x)
utf8ToInt(stripBom(x))
*/
```

gives

```
> x <- "\uFEFFabcdef"

> print(x)
[1] "abcdef"

> print(stripBom(x))
[1] "abcdef"

> identical(x, stripBom(x))
[1] FALSE

> utf8ToInt(x)
[1] 65279    97    98    99   100   101   102

> utf8ToInt(stripBom(x))
[1]  97  98  99 100 101 102
```

EDIT: What might also be useful is seeing how R does it internally -- there are a number of situations where R strips BOM (e.g. for its scanners and file readers). See:

https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/bfe73ecd848198cb9b68427cec7e70c40f96bd72/src/main/scan.c#L455-L458

https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/bfe73ecd848198cb9b68427cec7e70c40f96bd72/src/main/connections.c#L3950-L3957

Comment: This does not address the problem in either of the languages the OP tagged.

Comment: 1) Rcpp is a very important part of the R ecosystem and is useful for demonstrating / prototyping such problems, and that 2) it is trivial to translate this from C++ to C. Note that this example can be executed _in R_ with the Rcpp package, though `Rcpp::sourceCpp()`.

Comment: Perhaps you would be kind enough to add the C translation then? Or if it is preferable I could probably provide the code for one and make an edit?

Comment: @KevinUshey I added commit refs as the `trunk` links will refer to static line numbers not code... `scan.c` appeared to still be correct but `connections.c` definitely moved around since this post, please have a quick check to confirm I picked the right updated lines

Comment: Those look correct to me. Thank you very much for taking a look!

Answer (score 4):

Based on Kevin's Rcpp example I used the following C function to check for the bom:

```
SEXP R_parse(SEXP x) {
  /* get data from R */
  const char* json = translateCharUTF8(asChar(x));

  /* ignore BOM as suggested by RFC */
  if(json[0] == '\xEF' && json[1] == '\xBB' && json[2] == '\xBF'){
    warning("JSON string contains UTF8 byte-order-mark!");
    json = json + 3;
  }

  /* parse json */
  char errbuf[1024];
  yajl_val node = yajl_tree_parse(json, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));
}
```